# Solr Range Buckets and Long URLS

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I am looking to see if in Solr 3.4 it is possible to define a range of a field as a field itself so say:

```
Price : [0-1000]
Price : [1001-*]
```

That i could simply pass a field name in say PriceLow and PriceHigh for each of these.  I need to return facet count for upto 50 ranges and im concerned i will be limited by length passing them in via HTTP Get.  As the queries i am passing are very long as well.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're asking, could you please clarify?

Comment: Basically is their a way i can prebucket the information when it is being indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like explained [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-Facet-on-a-price-range-tt1846392.html#a1849958).
If you have many facet ranges, you can pre-compute the ranges as plain strings in another field during indexing playing around with regex. You can basically create a copyField of the following fieldType, on which every pattern is a different range:

```
<fieldtype name="priceclass" class="solr.TextField"> 
  <analyzer> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^([0-9]{0,2})([\.,][0-9]{1,2})?$" replacement="0 - 99" replace="all" /> 
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|)([\.,][0-9]{1,2})?$" replacement="100 - 249" replace="all" /> 
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(2[5-9][0-9]|[3-4][0-9][0-9])([\.,][0-9]{1,2})?$" replacement="250 - 499" replace="all" /> 
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^([5-9][0-9][0-9])([\.,][0-9]{1,2})?$" replacement="500 - 999" replace="all" /> 
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^([0-9]{4,5})([\.,][0-9]{1,2})?$" replacement="999 -" replace="all" /> 
  </analyzer> 
</fieldtype>
```

Then you can directly facet on the new copy field making a simple field facet.

This way you can avoid using long urls with many ranges, but if you need to change your ranges you'll need to reindex everything.